# Networkx: Multiple conditions for edges

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to generate a network through a dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [1,2,3,4,5],
                'roi': ['positive', 'negative', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative'],
                'description': ['middle', 'low', 'middle', 'high', 'low']})
df1 = df1.set_index('id_emp')
```

On the network that I am trying to develop, the nodes represent the values ​​of the id_emp column. And there are edges between two nodes if the `roi` AND `description` column values ​​are the same. Here is the code I'm using to develop:

```
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([a for a in df1.index])

for cr in set(df1['roi']):
    indices = df1[df1['roi']==cr].index
    G.add_edges_from(it.product(indices, indices))

for d in set(df1['description']):
    indices = df1[df1['description']==d].index
    G.add_edges_from(it.product(indices,indices))

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)
plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
nx.draw(G,pos,node_size = 100, width = 0.5,with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Problem: Edges are being generated for nodes as equal values ​​in the `description` OR `roi` columns. In the given example, node 4 should have no connection because it has a different value in the description column.

What should I do to analyze the two conditions together to have an edge between two nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a graph theory tool in such case. `NetworkX` would be interesting here if you wanted to find the connected components for instance (i.e linked nodes).

However if two given edges must connect exactly the same nodes for them to be considered as being part of the same component, that is essentially the same as obtaining a list of duplicate rows in the dataframe, which could be achieved by:

```
df1.roi.str.cat(df1.description, sep='-').reset_index().groupby('roi').id_emp.apply(list)

roi
negative-high         [4]
negative-low       [2, 5]
positive-middle    [1, 3]
Name: id_emp, dtype: object
```

Comment: The idea is to find communities. So you think this kind of approach I'm trying to use is not interesting?

Comment: No. Communities give some insights into which nodes are highly lined together. In this case it makes no sense, as you're not interested in linking together edges which do not share both nodes. Hence the only communities you'll get are edges with the same nodes @costa